# How to convert .opus file to .mp3/.m4a/.aac in iOS swift?

Tags: ios, swift, mp3, avaudioplayer, opus

I want to play **.opus** file using AVAudioPlayer, since AVAudioPlayer doesn't support **.opus** file, I am trying to find a way to convert **.opus** to any other audio format so that I can play using **AVAudioPlayer**.
Could anyone help me on this?

Thank you

Comment: As there is no Apple provided support yet, you can add this dependency https://code.videolan.org/videolan/VLCKit/tree/master#cocoapods

Answer (score 0):

You could use `libopus` or `libopusfile` C libraries to dynamically decode Opus files to raw PCM audio and feed that to a memory buffer that AVAudioPlayer could decode.  You would most likely need to prepend the memory buffer with AIFF/WAV/RIFF header bytes that describe the PCM data.

Comment: It does not work without 'AIFF/WAV/RIFF header bytes' (as you mentioned). Would you please give me some hints (code sample if possible) here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59597315/playing-custom-opus-audio-file-in-ios

Answer (score 0):

You could use the VLCKit library ;)

https://code.videolan.org/videolan/VLCKit/blob/master/README.md