# How to decode self-delimited opus in iOS

Tags: ios, avfoundation, avplayer, opus, vlckit

I was able to record and play opus using AVFoundation. The problem is I got a custom opus audio file as follows:

```
| header 1 (1 byte) | opus data 1 (1~255 bytes) | header 2 (1 byte) | opus data 2 (1~255 bytes) | ... | ... |
```

Each header indicates size of the opus data i.e. if header 1 is 200 (Int) then opus data 1 is 200 bytes

So, I am extracting opus data and appending to Data buffer as following:

```
guard let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "test_16kbps", withExtension: "opus") else { return }

do {

    let fileData = try Data(contentsOf: url)

    while index < fileData.count {

        headerData = fileData[index...(index + HEADER_SIZE)]

        let opusBytesFromHeader = Int([UInt8](headerData)[0])

        start = index + HEADER_SIZE
        end = start + opusBytesFromHeader

        opusData = fileData[start..<end]

        opusAudioData.append(opusData)

        index += (HEADER_SIZE + opusBytesFromHeader)
   }

} catch let err {
   print(err)
}
```

Then I tried to play using AVAudioPlayer as following

```
// ... ... ...

playData(audioData: opusAudioData)

// ... ... ...

func playData(audioData: Data){

   var avAudioPlayer: AVAudioPlayer?

    do {

        try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(.playback, mode: .default)
        try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(true)

        avAudioPlayer = try AVAudioPlayer.init(data: audioData)

        if let player = avAudioPlayer {
            player.play()
        } else {
            print("failed to create player from data")
        }

    } catch let error {
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }
}
```

Gives error: `The operation couldn’t be completed. (OSStatus error 1954115647.)`

I also tried **MobileVLCKit** pod as following:

```
if let opusFilePath = createNewDirPath() { // creates "foo.opus"
    do {
        try opusAudioData.write(to: opusFilePath)
        let opusMedia = VLCMedia(url: opusFilePath)
        vlcPlayer.media = opusMedia
        vlcPlayer.play()
    } catch let err {
        print(err)
    }
}
```

**Gives following error:**

```
2020-01-05 14:03:41.421270+0900 AppPlay[8695:4077367] creating player instance using shared library
[mp3 @ 0x10881e600] Failed to read frame size: Could not seek to 40126.
TagLib: Ogg::File::packet() -- Could not find the requested packet.
TagLib: Opus::File::read() -- invalid Opus identification header
```

Android team was able to play using libopus (JNI) and AudioTrack. So, I tried to decode opus data using **OpusKit** pod as following:

```
if let decoded = OpusKit.shared.decodeData(opusData) {
    decodedOpusData.append(decoded)
} else {
    print("failed to decode")
}
```

And then tried to play `decodedOpusData` using AVAudioPlayer but gives same error: `The operation couldn’t be completed. (OSStatus error 1954115647.)`.

I don't know what to do to play that audio file (I am new to opus).

About opus data

> Sample: 16000 | Frame size: 320 (16 * 20 ms) | Channel: 1

Comment: what does `decodeData()` return?  PCM 16 or float arrays?

Comment: @AnthumChris `public func decodeData(_ data: Data) -> Data? { var decodedData = [opus_int16](repeating: 0, count: 2048)  // ... ... ...  return outputData as Data }`: https://github.com/robertveringa89/OpusKit/blob/master/OpusKit/lib/OpusKit.swift#L52

Comment: @AnthumChris, it returns PCM 16

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Per your other comment/question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52738113/how-to-convert-opus-file-to-mp3-m4a-aac-in-ios-swift/53029364?noredirect=1#comment105366858_53029364), if you can get decoded PCM samples, you can add a RIFF/WAV using bytes similar to this C const below (taken from [WAV_HEADER_TEMPLATE](https://github.com/AnthumChris/opus-stream-decoder/blob/master/src/opus_chunkdecoder_test.c#L21))

```
// Header for a 48 kHz, stereo, 32-bit float WAV.
// http://www-mmsp.ece.mcgill.ca/Documents/AudioFormats/WAVE/WAVE.html
static const unsigned char WAV_HEADER_TEMPLATE[44]={
  'R','I','F','F',
  0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0x7F,  // file size
  'W','A','V','E',
  'f','m','t',' ',      // Chunk ID
  0x10,0x00,0x00,0x00,  // Chunk Size - length of format above
  0x03,0x00,            // Format Code: 1 is PCM, 3 is IEEE float
  0x02,0x00,            // Number of Channels (e.g. 2)
  0x80,0xBB,0x00,0x00,  // Samples per Second, Sample Rate (e.g. 48000)
  0x00,0xDC,0x05,0x00,  // Bytes per second, byte rate = sample rate * bits per sample * channels / 8
  0x08,0x00,            // Bytes per Sample Frame, block align = bits per sample * channels / 8
  0x20,0x00,            // bits per sample (16 for PCM, 32 for float)
  'd','a','t','a',
  0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0x7F   // size of data section
 };
```

[this C function](https://github.com/AnthumChris/opus-stream-decoder/blob/master/src/opus_chunkdecoder_test.c#L39) is also suggested to read.

- `0x01` should be used to specify PCM for format code
- "size of data" would be the total byte size of your decoded audio
  data.
- "file size" = 44 + "size of data"

(Complete solution: [Libopus Kit](https://hovermind.com/ios/libopus-kit)) **Swift code for iOS** (*Swift 5, iOS 13, Xcode 11.3*)

```
guard let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "foo", withExtension: "opus") else { return }
print("url: \(url)")

do {
    
    let fileData = try Data(contentsOf: url)
    
    let extractedPCM = AudioUtil.extractPCM(from: fileData, for: OpusAudioSetting(/*defaults*/))
    
    let wavHeader = AudioUtil.createWavHeader(pcmInfo: PCMInfo(/*defaults*/), pcmDataSizeInBytes: Int32(extractedPCM.count))
    //print("wavHeader: \([UInt8](wavHeader))")

    let wavAudioData = AudioUtil.generateWav(header: wavHeader, pcmData: extractedPCM)
    playData(audioData: wavAudioData)
    
    
} catch let error {
    print(error)
}
```

**AudioUtil**

```
import Foundation
import OpusKit

public class AudioUtil {

    private init(){}
    
    public static func createWavHeader(pcmInfo: PCMInfo, pcmDataSizeInBytes dataSize: Int32) -> Data {

        let WAV_HEADER_SIZE:Int32 = 44
        let fileSize:Int32 = dataSize + WAV_HEADER_SIZE
        
        let sampleRate:Int32 = 16000
        let subChunkSize:Int32 = 16
        let format:Int16 = 1
        let channels:Int16 = 1
        let bitsPerSample:Int16 = 16
        let byteRate:Int32 = sampleRate * Int32(channels * bitsPerSample / 8)
        let blockAlign: Int16 = (bitsPerSample * channels) / 8
        
        let header = NSMutableData()
        
        header.append([UInt8]("RIFF".utf8), length: 4)
        
        header.append(byteArray(from: fileSize), length: 4)
        
        //WAVE
        header.append([UInt8]("WAVE".utf8), length: 4)
        
        //FMT
        header.append([UInt8]("fmt ".utf8), length: 4)
        header.append(byteArray(from: subChunkSize), length: 4)
        
        header.append(byteArray(from: format), length: 2)
        header.append(byteArray(from: channels), length: 2)
        header.append(byteArray(from: sampleRate), length: 4)
        header.append(byteArray(from: byteRate), length: 4)
        header.append(byteArray(from: blockAlign), length: 2)
        header.append(byteArray(from: bitsPerSample), length: 2)
        
        
        header.append([UInt8]("data".utf8), length: 4)
        header.append(byteArray(from: dataSize), length: 4)
        
        return header as Data
    }

    public static func extractPCM(from audioData: Data, for setting: OpusAudioSetting) -> Data {
        
        OpusKit.shared.initialize(
            sampleRate: setting.sampleRate,
            numberOfChannels: setting.channels,
            packetSize: setting.packetSize,
            encodeBlockSize: setting.encodeBlockSize)
        
        let decodedPCMData = extractAndDecodeAudioData(from: audioData)
        
        return decodedPCMData
    }
    
    public static  func extractAndDecodeAudioData(from fileData: Data, headerSize: Int = 1) -> Data {
      // can not share this implementation
    }
    
    private static func byteArray<T>(from value: T) -> [UInt8] where T: FixedWidthInteger {
        // .littleEndian is required
        return withUnsafeBytes(of: value.littleEndian) { Array($0) }
    }

    public static func generateWav(header wavHeader: Data, pcmData: Data) -> Data {
        
        var wavData = Data()
        
        wavData.append(wavHeader)
        wavData.append(pcmData)
        
        return wavData
    }
}

public struct OpusAudioSetting {
    var sampleRate: opus_int32 = 16000
    var channels: opus_int32 =  1
    var packetSize: opus_int32 = 320
    var encodeBlockSize: opus_int32 = 320
}

public struct PCMInfo {
    var sampleRate:Int32 = 16000
    var channels:Int16 = 1
    var bitsPerSample:Int16 = 16
}
```

Comment: "This needs to be called twice" (https://github.com/AnthumChris/opus-stream-decoder/blob/master/src/opus_chunkdecoder_test.c#L41) => since I am appending all decoded chunks to `decodedOpusData`, should't I append header once (i.e. `finalData = Data(header + decodedOpusData)`) and then play (`avAudioPlayer = try AVAudioPlayer.init(data: finalData)`)?

Comment: How can I figure out those ("file size", "format code", and "size of data section") from my `decodedOpusData` mentioned that `decodedOpusData` is `[opus_int16]`. Is file size = `decodedOpusData.count` or `(decodedOpusData.count / MemoryLayout<UInt16>.stride)`? I guess format code is 1 (since `decodedOpusData` is array of `UInt16` from opus decoder) and I don't know what is "size of data section" (totally new to audio processing in iOS and opus)

Comment: It's working now. Should I answer separately with Swift code (what I did) or accept your one and suggest edit of your answer with swift code below your hints?

Comment: I got one more favor to ask. I can record opus using AVFoundation. But now I need to encode the recorded data same as : `| header 1 (1 byte) | opus data 1 (1~255 bytes) | header 2 (1 byte) | opus data 2 (1~255 bytes) | ... | ... |` (I thought the opus is processed in server but server team said I have to encode it in the same format and send it to server). Give me some hints on  how to achieve that (and when? while recording or after recording completed).

Comment: asked here (about encoding opus): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59622288/how-to-create-self-delimited-opus-audio-file-in-ios. Would you please take a look

Comment: @HassanTareq Hi, i checked your code but I cannot find how to use extractAndDecodeAudioData function, can you help me with that.?

Comment: @FarisMuhammed as you can see the comment `// can not share this implementation`, because I wrote that code for a client and therefore can not share it, It was specific to a implementation I was doing, from hints given above, try to solve your problem.